# Is this set containing all circles of rational radius connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Given $r>0$, let $C_r=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=r^2\}$. Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ having the following properties:

1. For all $r\in \mathbb{Q}$, $C_r\subset X$.
2. For all $r\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$, $X\cap C_r\neq \emptyset$.

Is $X$ connected?

My attempt:

I tried to prove that $X$ is not connected by considering, $A=\bigcup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}} C_r,$ and $B=X-A$. But I've not been able to prove that $A$ and $B$ are separated sets, that is, $\overline{A}\cap B=A\cap \overline{B}=\emptyset$.

Comment: Can i ask a dumb question Gersh? Haven’t done sets much ever and in years. I’m sure this is a dumb one, but I cannot get the intuition of this: Definition:


$E$ is disconnected if there exist two nonempty subsets $A$, $B$ of $X$ such that:

1. $E = A \cup B$
2. $A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$ and $\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset$

What is being lost in the following qualitative view:

$ \overline{B}$ is the compliment of B, ie everything not in B. Intersecting that with A gives us null, so “Everything not in B is not in A.” So why isnt $B \subset A$? And then A in B

Comment: Definition is from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115190/connecting-two-definitions-of-connectedness maybe is wrong? I assumed it must be me

Comment: @AlBrown The confusion is because $\overline{B}$ is not the complement, but the closure of $B$ ($=B$ plus the set of limit points of $B$)

Comment: @en3trix thank you makes sense now 

Comment: I think you mean "Let $X$ be _a_ subset" (because $X$ is not uniquely defined); and "Is $X$ _necessarily_ connected?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I found a proof to see $X$ is connected. Suppose $X\subset A\cup B$, where $X\cap A\neq \emptyset$, $X\cap B\neq \emptyset$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$, with $A,B$ open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose wlog that $C_1\subset A$, and let $a=\inf \{r^*>0 \,|\, \cup_{r^*<r<1, r\in \mathbb{Q}} C_r\subset A\}$, certainly $a<1$ because $C_1$ is compact and hence has a finite open cover contained in $A$. Suppose $a>0$, if $a$ is rational then $C_a$ can not be contained in $A$ since this would yield a contradiction: there exists a Lebesgue number $l>0$ such that every ball of radius $l$ centered in any point of $C_a$ is contained in $A$, then $A$ contains an open set with form of ring  which also contains a circumference of radius less than $a$; therefore $C_a\subset B$, but since $C_a$ is compact there is a finite open cover of $C_a$ contained in $B$ which also yields a contradiction, because $C_{a+\varepsilon}\subset A$ for small $\varepsilon>0$ such that $a+\varepsilon$ is rational. Hence $a$ is irrational, but then there exists a $(x,y)\in C_a \cap X$, supposing $(x,y)\in A$ would yield a contradiction because $A$ would have to contain a circumference of rational radius and less than $a$, using circumferences are connected, on the contrary if $(x,y)\in B$ would be also a contradiction, since $B$ would have to intersect circumferences contained in $A$. It follows that $a=0$. Now let $b=\sup\{r^*>0\,|\, \cup_{1<r<r^*,r\in \mathbb{Q}} C_r \subset A\}$, similarly one gets that $b=+\infty$. Therefore $A$ contains all circumferences of rational radius. As every point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an acummulation point of $A$, since it contains a dense subset, no point can be contained in $B$ which is also open, hence $B=\emptyset$ and $X$ is connected.

Comment: Also, note that in your try there are only two options, $X=A$ or $X =A \cup \{0\}$ (since $C_r$ is only defined for $r>0$ according to your post). In the first case $B=\emptyset$, whereas in the second case $B=\{0\}$, but the origin is an accumulation point of points in little circles of small and rational radius, so $\overline{A}=B$.

Comment: *Correction $B\subset \overline{A}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I have a question. You claim that $X=(D(0,\pi)\cap X)\cup ((\mathbb{R}^2-\overline{D(0,\pi)})\cap X)$. But, the truth is the above union is equal to $(\mathbb{R}^2-C_{\pi})\cap X$. So, how do you get to that separation?

Comment: Yes, since $C_\pi \cap X = \emptyset$ it follows that $X$ is contained in the complement of $C_\pi$, which has two open components and both intersect $X$, hence it follows the separation, each intersection is open in the relative topology and disjoint from each other, therefore $X$ is disconnected.

Comment: If you write $(\mathbb{R}^2 -C_\pi) \cap X$ certainly is also equal to the union of the sets I expressed, and equal to $X$, but it is not useful. What I did was expressing $X$ as union of open sets in the relative topology and disjoint from each other, which is an equivalent definition of disconnected set.

Comment: Notice that $X\cap C_{\pi}\neq \emptyset$ (property 2).

Comment: My fault, I read $=$

Comment: @Gerschgorin I edited my answer.

Comment: @Gerschgorin Now I added a proof. Sorry for my initial mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have some questions. For example. In the case when $a\in \mathbb{Q}$, how can you conclude that $C_a$ is not contained in $A$? I can get a contradiction by using the fact $A$ is open.

Comment: The idea is that if $C_a$ is contained in $A$, then you can create by compactness a kind of open cloud which contains $C_a$ and is contained in $A$, you can then create a circumference of radius less than $a$ contained in that cloud. You can try to make this process directly, or use the result of the Lebesgue number for compact sets to create this cloud, which in spirit is the same idea and maybe I should have mentioned it at first.

Answer (score 0):

Any continuous function $f:X\rightarrow\{T,F\}$ would induce a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow\{T,F\}$ defined by $g(x)=f(C_x\cap X)$. Notice the image of $g$ equals the image of $f$.

Comment: You can do better and remove a single point from each $C_r$, but not much better than that.

Comment: I liked your idea. Also, I think that to see $g$ is continuous may require some work, is there any easy way to prove it? Let me write my partial idea: we can define $x \sim y$ iff $x,y\in C_r$ for some $r\geq 0$ (taking $C_0=\{0\}$), and take the quotient space $X/ \sim$, since $f$ is constant on each equivalence class we can think it is defined in this quotient space so $g= h \circ f$, where $h:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow X/\sim$ and $h(x) = C_x \cap X$, it only rests to prove $h$ is continuous, which I think is the tricky part.

Comment: @en3trix To check $g$ is well defined, notice that each circle $C_r$ is partitioned into two open disjoint sets $f^{-1}(T)$ and $f^{-1}(F)$ since $C_r$ is connected this partition must be trivial, also $X\cap C_x$ is non empty for all $x\in\mathbb{R^+}$ so $g$ is well defined. Now for continuity since $f^{-1}(T)$ is closed and $\{C_r:r\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is dense, if $f(x)=T$ then there exists an annulus around $x$ whose intersection with $X$ gets sent to $T$. The radii of this annulus give an interval around $|x|$ in $\mathbb{R^+}$ which gets sent to $T$ under $g$.

Comment: @en3trix P.S. Notice $f^{-1}(T)$ is open so that the annulus does not degenerate into a circle. Also I think you got the well-defined part of $g$ in your partial idea, but I included it so it doesn't get overlooked, it gives insight into how to generalize the theorem.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What I thought about the existence of the annulus was (almost surely is the same idea a little extended): since $T$ is open there exists a $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \cap X \subset f^{-1}(T)$ therefore every circumference of rational radius intersecting $B(x,r)$ is mapped into $T$, and since $F$ is also open, no point of $X$ lying in a circumference of irrational radius intersecting $B(x,r)$ can be mapped into $F$, because $f^{-1}(T)$ contains a dense subset approaching these points, therefore the existente of the annulus.

Comment: @en3trix agreed, Using the basic open neighborhoods of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and the induced topology on $X$ are what I had in mind to prove the existence of the annulus.